# Add and Remove an Event Listener with an arrow function callback

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I am trying to add and remove an event listener to a button with javascript

callback:

```
let callback = (id) => alert(`This is a test Callback with id : ${id}`);
```

And it works when I use it with an event listener like this:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => callback(id));
```

but with this approach I am not able to `removeEventListener` because of the `arrow function`.
Is there a proper workaround for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a reference to the exact same function object, to be able to remove that specific event listener again.

So you have to store it into a variable, and then use that variable in both the addEventListener and removeEventListener calls.

```
let foo = () => callback(id);

document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', foo);

// ...

document.querySelector('#button').removeEventListener('click', foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let func = () => callback(id);
document.querySelector('#button').removeEventListener('click', func);
```